# Keep iOS webapp logged in

Tags: web-applications, ios8, iphone-standalone-web-app, iphone-web-app

I have a php web application which uses a cookie to keep a user logged in. When I add the web app to the home sceen in iOS 8 logging in becomes required every time the app is opened.

From other answers on here I have found this is due to web apps in iOS 7 and 8 not holding cookie or session data once closed, but no solution.

How should one approach keeping a web app logged in, in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
setcookie ('cookiename', 'value', time() + 86400);
echo $_COOKIE['cookiename'];
exit;
?>
```

This is what I am using for my web app.
http://spacehunter.org